# How can I get a list element to be "toggled" (JQuery) and then when this animation is done removed(), all upon a mouse click of the img in the <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, slidetoggle, removeclass

As it stands the remove function doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
var toggle = new function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'img', function () {
        $(this).parent().toggle('slide');
    })
}    
var remove = new function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'img', 
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }, 1000);
)
}
```

Comment: Why are you saving these event bindings as variables? Also why are you binding two click events to the same element?

Comment: What do you intend with that last parameter `1000` in the `.on()` call? `.on()` doesn't take any parameters after the event handler, does it?

Comment: Would it be better to just declare them instead? I did it this way so that they would be automatically called.

Comment: I updated it, I had the 1000 because I forgot to include the setTimeout function which is supposed to allow the previous animation to complete.

Comment: They aren't automatically called that way! The contrary! You need to explicitly call them using `toggle()` and `remove()` afterwards.

Comment: The toggle function seems to be automatically called when I click the img that is part of the <li>

Comment: By the way: I think the reason, why the `.remove()` didn't work in your code is because `this` is pointing to `window` within the `setTimeout()` callback: see http://jsfiddle.net/rbBgS/1/ (click on the blue box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function your are looking for is [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/). It will execute a provided callback after the previous animation has finished:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'img', function() {
    var $entry = $(this).parent();
    $entry.toggle('slide').queue(function(next) {
        $entry.remove();
        next();
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rbBgS/